# Xamarin change ListView Cell Color based on specified String in List bound to ArrayAdapter

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

i'm having some serious trouble switching colors of an Item in a ListView for Xamarin Android.

Here's what i need to do: I have a List of strings constructed from values of a MySQL DB inserted via a JSON API, if one if the strings that will become an Item in the ListView that is bound to the ListView via a ArrayAdapter contains the string "Urgent" than the whole Cell needs to be displayed in red in the ListView. I found some solutions changing the color based on the position of the cell by overriding a method of the ArrayAdapter but thats not what i need.

I'm using the Simple_ListView_1 Element provided by Android itself.

Anyone with a solution?

Comment: Actually, what you found is exactly what you need. To customize your cells, you have to implement your own adapter. Either by overriding methods in an existing one, or by making one from scratch.

Comment: And how do i search for the matching string if i override the Method of the ArrayAdapter?

Comment: What if you just set the cell color in `GetView`? Can you do something like  `if(cellContentString == "Urgent") // make cell red`?

Comment: Nope that doesn't work for me sadly

Comment: Well, it has to, because that's how you do it. :)

Comment: Could one of you provide a sample pls?